# How call GAE EndpointV2 from Java Client

Tags: google-app-engine, endpoint

How can I call GAE Endpoints V2 from my Java Client using google-api-client:1.23.0 library.

I followed the migration description (https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/migrating) for the backend . Deployment worked fine.

But using the generated endpoints client libs I get the error:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClient$Builder.setBatchPath(Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/google/api/client/googleapis/services/AbstractGoogleClient$Builder;
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:133)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClient$Builder.setBatchPath(Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/google/api/client/googleapis/services/AbstractGoogleClient$Builder;
    at com.example.qwarks.backend.qwarksApi.QwarksApi$Builder.setBatchPath(QwarksApi.java:2098)
    at com.example.qwarks.backend.qwarksApi.QwarksApi$Builder.<init>(QwarksApi.java:2077)
    at com.example.qwarks.utility.Api.<clinit>(Api.java:24)
    at com.example.qwarks.screens.SplashScreen.<init>(SplashScreen.java:105)
    at com.example.qwarks.Qwarks.create(Qwarks.java:59)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:149)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:126)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, I had to remove

compile project(path: ':backend', configuration: 'endpoints')

from my gradle dependencies

Comment: Can you accept your answer so that this post can be considered solved? Thanks